# Manage EditText when getting in edit mode

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using an **EditText** wich is waiting for an integer.

When the edit text isn't in edition mode it show something like: "**200 000 €**"

And when it enter in **edition mode** I want it to display "**200000**"

And then when leaving I want it to display "**200 000 €**" **back**.

I tried the **textEdit.setOnClickListener()** but it doesn't work well :/

Where can I catch those **events** ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a hint text on your edit text from xml. Use this to display the hint text when the edit text is not in focus.

```
android:hint="Write Caption"
```

You can set this through code also in your activity

```
editText.setHint("Hint text");
```